# Cloud storage 1.88.0 exception when accessing inputstream

Tags: java, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I just upgraded to google cloud storage java 1.88.0 from 1.76.0 on an app-engine standard. I ran into the below problem when trying to read a com.google.cloud.storage.Blob object. The workaround is not going to work for big documents on app-engine, so is there a solution to this? Maybe some dependency thing I would have to check?

```
ByteStreams.copy(Channels.newInputStream(blob.reader()), resp.getOutputStream());
```

now fails with

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Objects$Get.setReturnRawInputStream(Z)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClientRequest;
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.createReadRequest(HttpStorageRpc.java:658)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.read(HttpStorageRpc.java:693)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobReadChannel$1.call(BlobReadChannel.java:127)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobReadChannel$1.call(BlobReadChannel.java:124)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobReadChannel.read(BlobReadChannel.java:123)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:109)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:108)
```

but can be replaced with, as a workaround (but is probably vastly less memory efficient):

```
ByteSource.wrap(storage.readAllBytes(blob)).copyTo(resp.getOutputStream());
```

Relevant pom entries could be:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.88.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>28.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- firestore fails with NoClassDefFoundError: 
             com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3 without this -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for the same?

Comment: No, I did not try anything else yet.

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) documentation, in order to read and write from a Cloud Storage Bucket you should be using the appengine tools dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

After following the previously mentioned documentation my App Engine App works just fine.

Please try this documentation and tell us if works for you.

Comment: The documentation you are pointing to refers to the old "non recommended" way of accessing a bucket, so that is not what we are using here (as you can see from the post, we are using "com.google.cloud.storage.Blob" so using the new https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-cloud-storage, https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java way). I anyway tried your suggestion but am unsurpringly getting the same error. Btw, this was working before the change to 1.88.0 I think.